# How to get year, month and day from different timezone?

Tags: java, android

I am now in Hong Kong. How can I get the year, month and day from USA??
I have tried:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

But I don't know how to get the year, month.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code results in the three needed variables:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar LATime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
LATime.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
int year = LATime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = LATime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int date = LATime.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry the date return 17, but should be 16

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like below (assuming dateObj is date instance of hongkong time):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
String usaDateStr= sdf.format(dateObj);
```

See this [example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/200.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a useful lib for date-time manipulation like [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) lib

I did try to use it when converting UTC time to local time, you may try it to convert between different time-zones.
Good luck ! :)